# Get elements of an object

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript program, I get values of a JSON file and then I push them to an array. But when I try to get the elements of that array, it doesn't return anything.

Here's the function which pushes the temperatures:

```
temperatures = []
get_info = (data) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(data)
    for(var i = 0; i < data['list'].length; i++){
        temperatures.push(String(data['list'][i]['main']['temp']))
    }
}
```

Here I get the data and call the function:

```
weather = (city_name) => {
var key = '.......';
var base_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?';
var url = base_url + 'appid=' + key + '&q=' + city_name + '&units=metric';
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(contents => get_info(contents))    
}
```

When I log `temperatures` it displays an empty array `[]`.

How can I get the elements of the temperatures array?

Comment: can you show me json object?

Comment: Here's the link for the json data: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=0e0bd4dcfedac7fe749c8a42a2c04b4b&q=Korinthos,GR&units=metric

Comment: Where is the `console.log(temperatures)` located? `get_info` seems to be an asynchronous function.

Comment: But I only keep the temperatures that are in ["list"][i]["main]["temp"]

Comment: Console.log data after you parse it, do you see an object? Is data.list an array? Also, as an aside, you can use syntax like data.list[I].main.temp

Comment: Your code works without change: https://jsfiddle.net/k97qzL3u/2/ . Do you actually call your `get_info()` function properly ?

Comment: @ajobi I added the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work just fine. You have take into account that the *fetch* operation is asynchronous, so you will only have the data available in the *temperatures* variable when the promise is resolved.

You can check that the variable *temperatures* is storing the right values by console logging after calling the *get_info* method:

```
weather = (city_name) => {
    var key = '.......';
    var base_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?';
    var url = base_url + 'appid=' + key + '&q=' + city_name + '&units=metric';
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(contents => {
            get_info(contents);

            console.log(temperatures); // --> Here the data is available!
        });    
};
```

---

As a side note, if you know that the API is returning a JSON, you could call the `json` method of the response instead of calling the `text` method and then parsing the text through `JSON.parse`:

```
temperatures = [];
get_info = (data) => {
    for(var i = 0; i < data['list'].length; i++){
        temperatures.push(String(data['list'][i]['main']['temp']))
    }
};

weather = (city_name) => {
    var key = '.......';
    var base_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?';
    var url = base_url + 'appid=' + key + '&q=' + city_name + '&units=metric';
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(contents => {
            get_info(contents);

            console.log(temperatures); // --> Here the data is available!
        });    
};
```

Comment: Yea I get the temperatures fine, but how can I get the first temperature in temperatures?

Comment: You can get the first temperature by getting the first element in the array (`temperatures[0]`).

Comment: how can I make the code to wait until all the temperatures are available?

Comment: You are already waiting with the use of `then` :). If you put your code in the same place I put the `console.log`, the data should be available.

Comment: Ahhhh, makes sense. Thanks :D